# added root in grape api but not included in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am following [this](https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/making-a-rails-api-with-grap/) article to learn about writing api using [grape gem](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape). But in the response I am not getting the root key. Here is my directory structure,

```
app
 |––controllers
       |––api
           |––base.rb
           |––v1
               |––base.rb
               |––graduates.rb
```

In app/controllers/api/v1/graduates.rb:

```
module API
  module V1
    class Graduates < Grape::API
      include API::V1::Defaults
  resource :graduates do
    desc "Return all graduates"
    get "", root: :graduates do
      Graduate.all
    end

    desc "Return a graduate"
    params do
      requires :id, type: String, desc: "ID of the 
        graduate"
    end
    get ":id", root: "graduate" do
      Graduate.where(id: permitted_params[:id]).first!
    end
  end
end
```

end
end

in app/controllers/api/v1/defaults.rb

```
module API
  module V1
    module Defaults
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    prefix "api"
    version "v1", using: :path
    default_format :json
    format :json
    formatter :json, 
         Grape::Formatter::ActiveModelSerializers

    helpers do
      def permitted_params
        @permitted_params ||= declared(params, 
           include_missing: false)
      end

      def logger
        Rails.logger
      end
    end

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
      error_response(message: e.message, status: 404)
    end

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |e|
      error_response(message: e.message, status: 422)
    end
  end
end
```

end
end

I have used `grape-active_model_serializers` gem to serialize like the following,
In app/serializers/graduate_serializer.rb

```
class GraduateSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

I got the following output. `[{"id":1,"name":"aaaa"},{"id":2,"name":"bbbb"},{"id":3,"name":"cccc"},{"id":4,"name":"dddd"}]`

But As I added  `get "", root: :graduates do` in `app/controllers/api/v1/graduates.rb` file, I am expecting the following output,

```
{"graduates": [{"id":1,"name":"aaaa"},{"id":2,"name":"bbbb"},{"id":3,"name":"cccc"},{"id":4,"name":"dddd"}]}
```

What I am missing. why `graduates` is not added as root. Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty fix: use in `app/controllers/api/v1/graduates.rb`

```rb
get "" do
    { graduates: Graduate.all }
end
```

Or you can delete gem `grape-active_model_serializers`, delete class `GraduateSerializer`, delete row `formatter :json, Grape::Formatter::ActiveModelSerializers` from `defaults.rb`, and add gem [grape-entity](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity) to Gemfile, install it, add code to `app/app/entities/graduate_entity.rb`:

```rb
class GraduateEntity < Grape::Entity
  root 'graduates', 'graduate'

  expose :id
  expose :name
end
```

Change code in `app/app/controllers/api/v1/graduates.rb`:

```rb
get "" do
  present Graduate.all, with: GraduateEntity
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with similar issue as you, I resolved it by adding

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
```

in `config/initializers/serializer.rb`

Let me know if it could help you